# How to control navigation by default string resource in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview, navigation

***I have successfully completed a navigation into `RecyclerViewAdapter` to navigate many destinations by `string` Resource.*** Because I have many lists, and each `TextView` it's about separate `fragment`.

It's wonderful to do it. **But I have a small problem.** That's I have **2** `string` Resource, **"en"** English as a default and **"ar"** as a second language.

**My app is working well when I use it by English locale. But it crashes when I use it by Arabic locale.**

### What I want is:

To control or force the app when it converts to Arabic to still use the default, which is English string resource.

---

**Here's the `RecyclerViewAdapter` code block:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SubSectionListHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = dataset[position]
    holder.subSectionView.text = context.resources.getString(item.subSectionSrcID)
    holder.subSectionView.setOnClickListener {
        val stringConvertToId = it.resources.getIdentifier(
            context.resources.getString(item.subSectionSrcID).replace("\\s".toRegex(), ""),
            "id",
            context.packageName)
        it.findNavController().navigate(stringConvertToId)
    }
}
```

**Here's sample of the `navGraph` tag:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/CreateOrder"
    android:name=".PoCreateOrderFragment"
    android:label="@string/btnStr_crtOrder"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_po_create_order">
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/ReceivedPreOrders"
    android:name=".PoRcOrdersFragment"
    android:label="@string/str_whPo_rcvdPrm"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_po_rc_orders">
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/DeferredPreOrders"
    android:name=".PoDfOrdersFragment"
    android:label="@string/str_whPo_dfrdPrm"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_po_df_orders">
</fragment>
```

**Here's sample of the default `string` Resource tag:**

```
<string name="btnStr_crtOrder">Create Order</string>
<string name="str_whPo_rcvdPrm">Received PreOrders</string>
<string name="str_whPo_dfrdPrm">Deferred PreOrders</string>
```

**Here's sample of the Arabic `string` Resource tag:**

```
<string name="btnStr_crtOrder">إضافة طلب</string>
<string name="str_whPo_rcvdPrm">الطلبيات المستلمة</string>
<string name="str_whPo_dfrdPrm">الطلبيات المؤجلة</string>
```

---

**To completely reach my idea to you.**

Answer (score 2):

This is really brittle (as you're finding out!) and you're just going to create headaches for yourself with this kind of complicated stuff. You should really keep the UI (e.g. the text being displayed) completely separate from the business logic (in this case, uniquely identifying each item and doing a specific action based on which one is clicked). The way you're doing it, it completely breaks whenever the display text is changed

You're already holding a list of `item`s with a resource string ID, right? And looking them up by index using the `RecyclerView` position. If I were you, I'd just create a lookup associating each `item` with a hardcoded navigation resource ID.

You could make another list with all the navigation IDs and use `position` to grab the correct one. Or you could make a `Map` associating each string resource ID with its navigation ID:

```
val labelsToDestinations = mapOf(
    R.string.btnStr_crtOrder to R.id.createOrder,
    ...
)

// in onBindViewHolder
holder.subSectionView.setOnClickListener {
    val destination = labelsToDestinations[item.subSectionSrcID]
    it.findNavController.navigate(destination)
}
```

That way, it doesn't matter what the *value* of the string resource is, you're just looking it up by the resource's *ID*. The value can change (different languages, different wording) and that doesn't matter.

---

Or just make it another property on the `item` (e.g. `item.destinationId`), like your label string ID already is. Personally, if I have a fixed set of things I need to define like this, I usually make an enum (you could use a sealed class if you want:

```
enum class DestinationItem(@StringRes labelId: Int, @IdRes navigationId: Int) {
    CREATE_ORDER(R.string.btnStr_crtOrder, R.id.createOrder)
    RECEIVED_PRE_ORDERS(R.string.str_whPo_rcvdPrm, R.id.receivedPreOrders)
    ...
}

val items = DestinationItem.values()
```

then you can generate your list of `item`s from that, and you have access to all the important IDs on the item itself. You can easily change which resources they use without affecting anything else - you can use a different label resource to control the display, that won't affect the navigation ID because it's a completely separate property

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.
But where I use `enum class` after creating it. Can you plz explain how?

Comment: It's just a way of defining your list of destinations, and any properties associated with them (navigation ID, label, etc). You're already using something like that in your RecyclerView adapter - whatever `dataset` contains. When you grab `item` from that, you can look at its label resource ID, right? This is the same idea, it's just adding an explicit navigation ID property. You can create your list of destinations for `dataset` like in the example (`DestinationItem.values()`) or you could do something like `listOf(CREATE_ORDER, SOMETHING_ELSE)` to only include specific items, or reorder them

Comment: I still didn't understand the enum class example. But I fully understood your `mapOf()` idea. And I tested, it successed . So, I could mark your answer as the correct answer

Comment: It's just collecting all your data about destinations in one place, so you can define them and access them neatly. Then anywhere you need to handle those destinations in your app, you can just reference that class, and all the info is right there. A lookup map is fine, but creating an object with all the info you need can be a lot easier to work with! Plus you can do things like ``navigate(DestinationItem.CREATE_ORDER.navigationId)`` from anywhere in your app, and it's easy to read. Just an option you have!

Comment: I got your meaning now. but this `.navigate()` I implemented it into `Adapter`. So, Should I write all `enum class` destinations into navtigate parameter? Becuase it's adapter.

Comment: The enum class up there is just a way of defining and storing the data about your destinations in one place. So your ``dataset`` can be the enum instances, in ``onBindViewHolder`` you can just use ``item.labelId`` for the string lookup, and use ``item.navigationId`` in your ``navigate`` call in the click listener. If the lookup map works for you then don't worry about it - if you start repeating the same code in different places, you might want to put it all in one place, which is what the enum does. That's all!